# Latex inside r code chunk?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Is it possible to insert a LaTeX code in a `r` code chunk?

I'm printing tables in a loop (using results='asis'option, I know I can use `print` to display some text, but ideally I would love each table to be in a separate `\subsection`, or at least to display comments with nicely formatted formulas.

```
...
\section{Section}

<<echo=FALSE, results="asis">>=
for (i in 1:3) {
  # here I want to insert a subsection with a title contating for instance x^i
  plot(i:(i*10), col=i) 
}
@
...
```

Anyone struggling with this also?

Comment: can you give a few more details/a minimum workable example?  If you want to insert raw LaTeX all you have to do is remember to escape the backslashes `\\` appropriately ...

Comment: try `cat("\\subsection")`

Comment: Thank you both. So obvious, yet I did not figure it out.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question based on @Benjamin's comment (there may be a time window before you can do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Benjamin's and @Ben Bolker's comments I now know the answer:

```
...
\section{Section}

<<echo=FALSE, results="asis">>=
for (i in 1:3) {
  cat('\\subsection{$x^', i, '$}')
  plot(i:(i*10), col=i) 
}
@
\end{document}
...
```